# Javascript, solution needed for async issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Currently creating an application using Angular, socket.io and express. However, I run in an async issue which I have a hard time getting a solution for. Here is the code:

```
  export class WebsocketService {

  this.socket;

  public connect() {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: { token: token } });
  }

  public getSocket () {

      // this function should only return this.socket when it is available

      return this.socket;

  }
```

The idea is that first somewhere in the application somewhere there is connected once with the websocket, the io functions is thus called once:

```
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: { token: token } });
```

Then in rest of the application the `this.socket` property should be passed around. However, `this.socket` should always return the object and should wait for it if it isn't present.

The implementation should also deal with the other parts of the application who try to call `getSocket` and get returned undefined. Basically, getSocket should never return undefined it should wait for connection and then return `this.socket`.

I tried playing around with promises a bit but I can't seem to find an elegant solution.

Comment: You mean the promise should wait for someone calling `connect()` on the service?

Comment: If `io` immediately returns a socket (as it appears to in the code above), why would you need a promise? Just construct it on demand (or in `connect` if you prefer) and return it as needed...?

Comment: io is async so it doesn't immediately return

Comment: @WillemvanderVeen - Well, your code treats it like it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know why you need the `connect` method , but here is one approach

```
export class WebsocketService {

  getSocket() {

    // this function should only return this.socket when it is available

    if (!this.socket || (this.socket && this.socket.disconnected)) {

      this.socket = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        const s = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: { token: token } });

        s.on('connect', () => {
          console.log(socket.connected); // true
          resolve(s);
        });

        s.on('disconnect', () => {
          console.log(socket.disconnect); // true
          reject(s);
        });
      });
    }

    return this.socket;
  }
}
```

Then, usage is:

```
service.getSocket().then(socket => {
    // Use the socket
});
```

Or with async/await:

```
const socket = await service.getSocket();
// Use the socket
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class WebsocketService {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { query: { token: token }})
    public getSocket () {
        return new Promise((res) => {
           while (!this.socket.connected) {}
           res(this.socket)
        })
    }
}
```

then call: `service.getSocket().then((socket) => {})`

Only give you the socket when it's connected. This assumes that the socket will be able to reconnect, but some errors can be expected if never able to reconnect.

Comment: Busy waits are **never** a good idea. In browser-based JavaScript code on the main UI thread (where Angular runs), they're a **particularly** bad idea.

Comment: Ok, I should probably add a timeout so `!this.socket.connected` isn't evaluated constantly. But, the code execution isn't blocked because it's a Promise. I wrote this with minimal knowledge of the API, but from what I understood the Socket object attempts to reconnect infinite times whenever it loses a connection. If it can't reconnect ever, then some error handling needs to be put in place.

Comment: *"But, the code execution isn't blocked because it's a Promise."* No, that isn't how promises work. Promises are for *observing* asynchronous completions. They don't make something synchronous asynchronous. Your `getSocket` will never return, locking up the UI of the browser.

Comment: If `this.socket.connected` is false when time originates, then `this.socket.connected` is true after a variable amount of seconds, that is a proxy for an asynchronous event.

Comment: No, because you have the main JavaScript thread busy with a busy-wait. Just try it. And even if it did work, locking up the UI of the browser for those seconds would make for awful UX (but again: it won't, because the JavaScript job to set `connected` to `true` will be blocked by your busy-wait, unless the socket is an exotic object [in spec terms]). I suggest doing some reading up on how the JavaScript event loop (HTML spec terminology) / "job queue" (JavaScript spec terminology) works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that a 'busy-wait' would block all other execution. I suppose when I learned this construct I would have been instructed to put a sleep or timeout in the loop, and forgetting this, it breaks.